# WCF Service - Startup takes extra time

Tags: performance, wcf

I find that WCF service will take 8-10 seconds to load the first hit.  After that it will take less than a second.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What kind of binding are you using?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: It [could be worse](http://ayende.com/blog/archive/2010/08/31/it-really-happened-legacy-programmers-tales.aspx).

Comment: @FreshCode: i am using wsHTTP
@James: 3.5 framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably due to .NET's cold start.  Have you looked at setting up the **IIS Warmup Module** which initializes dependancies before an initial request?

From the [Learn IIS website](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/688/using-the-iis-application-warm-up-module/)

1. **Decrease the response time for first requests** by pre-loading worker processes. The IIS Application Warm-Up module lets you configure the Web application to be pre-loaded before the first request arrives so that the worker process responds to the first Web request more quickly.
2. **Increase reliability by pre-loading worker processes** when overlapped recycling occurs. Because the recycled worker process in an overlapped recycling scenario only communicates its readiness and starts accepting requests after it finishes loading and initializing the resources as specified by the configuration, pre-loading the dependencies reduces the response times for the first requests.
3. **Customize the pre-loading of applications**. You can configure the IIS Application Warm-Up module to initialize Web applications by using specific Web pages and user identities. This makes it possible to create specific initialization processes that can be executed synchronously or asynchronously, depending on the initialization logic. In addition, these procedures can use specific identities to ensure a proper initialization.

Comment: My server still has IIS 7.5 so I simply schedule a task to wget my site every 15 minutes. Your warmup frequency would vary.